# How to change the font size of the color bar of a GeoPandas choropleth plot

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib

When I try to use the legend_kwds argument to change the font size of my colorbar, I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fontsize'

```
ax = df.plot(figsize=(20,16), alpha=0.8, column='value', legend=True, cmap='OrRd', legend_kwds={'fontsize':20})

plt.show()
```

Does anyone know how I can increase the font size of the colorbar with GeoPandas? I can't seem to find a keyword that works. I'm using GeoPandas 0.8.1 and Matplotlib 3.3.1.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the plot

Comment: So if I omit "legend_kwds={'fontsize':20}" the plot outputs normally it's just that there appears to be a bug in GeoPandas that prevents this argument from working, the plot doesn't really help contribute much to debugging.

Comment: I thought you by colorbar meant bar plot but I understand now from the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a  [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) problem and not a GeoPandas problem.

See the solution of [Seb Bacon](https://gist.github.com/sebbacon): [geopandas-legend-font-size.ipynb](https://gist.github.com/sebbacon/60ceec549f1d461af4543ccc5024c095?short_path=839cef5)

As the Jupyter notebook has problems (error opening it), I describe it here.

> The legend is actually a Colorbar object. To change the legend's font size, we have to get hold of the Colorbar's Axes object, and call .tick_params() on that.

```
import geopandas as gpd
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')) 
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")] 
world['gdp_per_cap'] = world.gdp_md_est / world.pop_est
```

> First, we call the .plot() method as usual, but we capture the return value which is the Axes of the map.

```
ax = world.plot(column='gdp_per_cap', cmap='OrRd', legend=True)
```

> We can use this to get hold of the Figure that contains the Axes.

fig = ax.figure

> The Figure has two Axes: one for the map, and one for the Colorbar. The one we care about is the second one.

```
cb_ax = fig.axes[1]
```

> We can now set the font size for the Colorbar. Other parameters for tick_params are documented at: [matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html)

```
cb_ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)
```

[image]

```
cb_ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter `shrink`:

```
plt.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax, shrink=0.5)
```